# ProfileOptimization .net4.5 for a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, jit, multicore

I just upgraded my web application hosted on IIS to .net 4.5 and was trying to get up to speed with all the nuances in .net 4.5. One of them is Multicore JIT (ProfileOptimization). Per this blog there's nothing that needs to be done to enable Multicore JIT if running an ASP.NET application after upgrading to .net 4.5. It's available by default.

**Question**: Does anybody know where the "profile" file created by default for an ASP.NET application located on the server? Just curious to see what it looks like for my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt683795) article:

> For ASP.NET and Silverlight apps, you’ll probably be using an
>   app-relative directory. In fact, starting with ASP.NET 4.5 and
>   Silverlight 4.5, background JIT is enabled by default and the profiles
>   are stored next to the app.